# SignalR client-server connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have been trying to find out the issue for the whole day and couldn't figure it out.
This is my SignalR Hub (**BlazorServerAppHub.cs**)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
    using BlazorServerApp.Data;
    
    namespace BlazorServerApp
    {
        public class BlazorServerAppHub: Hub
        {
            public const string HubUrl = "/chat";
      
            public async Task Broadcast(WeatherForecast[] forecasts)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", forecasts);
            }
    
            public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
            {
                return base.OnConnectedAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the business logic page (**WeatherForecastService.cs**)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using BlazorServerApp.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace BlazorServerApp.Data
{
    public class WeatherForecastService  
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<BlazorServerAppHub> _hubContext;

        public WeatherForecastService(IHubContext<BlazorServerAppHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }
        
        protected  async Task Broadcast()
        {
            var forecasts = await GetForecastAsync();
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Broadcast", forecasts);
        }

        public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
        }    
                
    }

 public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public int A { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Finally, this is my razor page (**FetchData.razor**)

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using BlazorServerApp.Data;
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.A</td>
                    
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {

    private  WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string baseUri = navigationManager.BaseUri;
        string hubUrl = baseUri.TrimEnd('/') + BlazorServerAppHub.HubUrl;

        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(hubUrl).Build();
        _hubConnection.On< WeatherForecast[]>("Broadcast", forcast => { forecasts = forcast; StateHasChanged(); });

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to get data from the server and push it to the client periodically. The Problem is my page when I run the app `forecasts` in **FetchData.razor** is empty so the page shows "Loading". Why is that? My guess is I am missing something in SignalR communication.

Comment: The hub/connection setup seems okay. How are you using/calling `WeatherForecastService` to push the data periodically?

Comment: First, I want to show one sample. Make sure every client connect can see the same data (since I generate them randomly). Then I will add that logic (still not sure in client-side or server-side). The problem is it is not working for even one sample.

Comment: That makes sense. You still need to call `WeatherForecastService.Broadcast()` on the server in order to send the message to the clients. Are you doing that somewhere?

Comment: Apparently, that is what I am missing. Where could I possibly call that? I need that to run when the page is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the server to periodically push the data to the client, you'll need to run some sort of background service. There are a number of ways to do that, for example:

- [Background tasks with hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire)

However, since you said you just want to send the data once for testing purposes, you can hook into `Hub.OnConnectedAsync()` to send the data to the client when they initially connect. First, I'd suggest creating a separate interface/repository for `Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync()`:

```
public interface IWeatherForecastRepository
{
    Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync();
}

public class WeatherForecastRepository
{
    private static readonly string[] Tickers = new[]
    {
        "10", "20", "30", "44", "77"
    };

    private static readonly int[] Ones = new[]
    {
        1000, 15000, 7000, 500, 2200
    };

    public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            A = index,
            B = Tickers[index - 1],
            C = NextFloat(rng),
            D = Ones[index - 1],
            E = rng.Next(0, 10000),
        }).ToArray());
    }

    static float NextFloat(Random random)
    {
        double decimalPart = random.NextDouble();
        double intPart = random.Next(0, 1000);

        return (float)Math.Round(intPart + decimalPart, 3); ;
    }
}
```

Then, once you register that repository with DI, you can inject it into your `BlazorServerAppHub` and use it in `OnConnectedAsync()`:

```
public class BlazorServerAppHub : Hub
{
    public const string HubUrl = "/chat";

    private readonly IWeatherForecastRepository _weatherForecastRepository;

    public BlazorServerAppHub(IWeatherForecastRepository weatherForecastRepository)
    {
        _weatherForecastRepository = weatherForecastRepository;
    }

    public async Task Broadcast(WeatherForecast[] forecasts)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", forecasts);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();

        var forecasts = await _weatherForecastRepository.GetForecastAsync();

        // Clients.Caller will only send the data to the client that just connected
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Broadcast", forecasts);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gray_Rhino no problem. The code seems generic enough that it'd be fine, but certainly feel free to delete it if not